# Prevent Spring caching for a specific class

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

In some code there is an interface method with a spring cacheable annotation. I have a decorator of a class that is altering this method. The code is basically

```
interface Foo {
  @Cacheable
  Widget doit();
}

class StandardFoo implements Foo {
   public Widget doit();
}

class FooDecorator implements Foo {
  Foo decorated;

  public Widget doit() {
    Widget = decorated.doit();
    ..some fun stuff
    return new SlightlyDifferentWidget();
  }
}
```

My problem comes as during the call chain the decorator is called, then the decorated object is called. Spring (or Ehcache) then decides to cache the objects returned by the decorated instance. `FooDecorator` then happily returns a modified widget the first time.

On the second call Spring sees an invocation of `Foo.doit()` (which is actually `FooDecorator.doit()`) and returns the objects it has cached (which are incorrectly the values from `StandardFoo.doit()`).

So what I would like to do is add configuration somewhere that tells Spring / Ehcache to only cache values from `DecoratedFoo` or to not cache the value returned by the other implementation.

Note that removing the `@Cacheable` annotation from the interface is not an available option.

Answer (score 2):

`@Cacheable` has a conditional caching feature (see [35.3.1 Conditional caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition)). The conditional parameter takes a SpEL expression.

```
interface Foo {
    @Cacheable(condition = "doCache")
    Widget doit(boolean doCache);
}
```

The `doCache` parameter (or some more elegant SpEL) could be use to control the caching. Types can be matched like `foo instanceof T(Bar)`.

Hope this helps.